# Adding a title attribute to an image that I linked to

Tags: php, html, title

I pulled images from my database and put them in a table, when I go over the image then, I see my `imgtitle` which is what I want. But now I used  `a href` to open a new page with the enlarged picture when I click on it. But how can I have the `imgtitle` on that pic as well when I go over it?

Here is the line of code:

```
<td><a href="<?= $image ?>"><img src="<?= $image ?>" title="<?= $imgtitle ?>" height="100" width="100"></a></td>
```

Comment: Is that anchor href pointing to an image file or to another webpage with the image on it? It's only possible to do what you're looking for with the latter.

Comment: you can title anything you want, if you control the html for that thing...

Comment: yes it's a image file. not a website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have title attribute in **a** and **img** element.
If you want to show the tooltip text again in the other page with the big picture, you have to use title there as well.

This is W3C's documentation on [HTML Global title attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp):

> In HTML5, the title attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).
>   In HTML 4.01, the title attribute cannot be used with: base, head, html, meta, param, script, style, and title.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<a href="<?= $image ?>" title="<?= $imgtitle ?>">
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: i tried this but then it gives me the title before i click it. not after when im redirected to the next page